# HTML colour picker in windows

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cross-domain

Html colour (`input type = "colour"`) picker shows user the bottom pen icon to get the colour from dom.
It works in mac but it doesn't show up in windows.

1. is there a way to show that option in windows as well
2. if not,what are some good options we have(javascript/ angular 1
   library)

to pick colour from a image in the html.
I found this https://www.script-tutorials.com/creating-an-html5-canvas-image-color-picker/, but it shows cross origin issues with tainted canvas. 
any suggestions?

for reference :

In mac os(chrome) the colour picker by default shows the pen icon in the bottom which lets you choose any colour by clicking on the background
[(in mac os)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjClN.png).
Same colour picker shows a different ui for windows system(chrome)
[(in windows system)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BunaM.png)

Comment: I'm guessing that "mac" refers to the Apple MacOS operating system - which doesn't have much to do with HTML - that's a browser / webserver thing. As for "windows" - that could mean all sorts of things. I think you really meant to tell us that you saw different behaviour in different browsers - but forgot to tell us what browsers you are actually describing.

Comment: @symcbean so i meant mac as in Apple MacOS operating system and windows 10 os.i am using chrome.i just added 2 images in my question

Answer (score 0):

The need of using a different colour picker than the html 5 colour picker is because in windows os html colour picker doesn't let you select colour of the clicked pixel(some background).

[colour picker library](https://www.script-tutorials.com/creating-an-html5-canvas-image-color-picker/)

I ended up using a colour picker library which paints the image in a canvas and then using canvas function getImageData i can look for mouseevent and get the colour at the clicked pixel of the image.

caution:when you use a image in a canvas make sure they are part of same server otherwise getImageData function will show cross origin issues